# Customize style of window alert text

Tags: customization

I am trying to customize the text of the window alert but in front end i see this

`<p class="custom-alert"><span class="custom-alert-title" style="color: red; font-weight: bold;">ΣΗΜΑΝΤΙΚΗ ΕΙΔΟΠΟΙΗΣΗ:</span> Κάντε τις απαραίτητες επιλογές σε μεγέθη, σχέδια ή χρώματα πριν προσθέσετε αυτό το προϊόν στο καλάθι σας.</p>`

code was used into functions.php

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_script_data', 'change_alert_text', 10, 2 );
function change_alert_text( $params, $handle ) {
    if ( $handle === 'wc-add-to-cart-variation' ) {
        $custom_alert = '<p class="custom-alert"><span class="custom-alert-title" style="color: red; font-weight: bold;">ΣΗΜΑΝΤΙΚΗ ΕΙΔΟΠΟΙΗΣΗ:</span> Κάντε τις απαραίτητες επιλογές σε μεγέθη, σχέδια ή χρώματα πριν προσθέσετε αυτό το προϊόν στο καλάθι σας.</p>';
        $params['i18n_make_a_selection_text'] = $custom_alert;
    }
    return $params;
}
```